# How to make my application has "Move to SD Card" button in Application Manager?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I saw many applications have "Move to SD Card" button on their application

[image]

I want my application has this button too. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.prgguru.sdmovable"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
```

add android:installLocation="auto" in your androidmanifest.xml file like above.

Comment: What next? How it will happen, that it will be on SD now?

Comment: Yes. It should work. For more details follow the steps in 
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-create-android-app-with-movable-to-sd-card-feature/